# Is it possible to implement security in jboss eap 6.4 using database?

Tags: security, jboss, console

How can i secure jboss eap 6.4 without using add-user.properties, i.e. to get users from DB? Is it possible to disable the default feature and get users from DB?

Edit: any links or suggestions?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to just use the JBoss security realms? [chap security realms](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html/security_guide/chap-security_realms) - everythings encrypted if you user the userAdd.sh script (maybe it's addUser.sh)

Comment: is this better in server fault? I'm reserving judgement for now, pls. advise.

Comment: @JGlass- Just want to understand more about how to implement security.